# How do I solve this index out of range issue in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand why I get an error that my code is out of range when running it and how to fix this. The tester code to run along side my code can be found here: https://github.com/ikokkari/PythonProblems/blob/main/tester109.py

Here is my code.

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    indexA = 0
    indexB = 1
    if tiles == []:
        return True
    if tiles[0][0] != tiles[-1][1]:
        return False
    for i in range(len(tiles)-1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            indexB -= 1
        indexB
        if tiles[indexA][indexB + 1] == tiles[indexA + 1][indexB]:
            indexA += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of a call to your `domino_cycle()` that causes the error, as well as the exact error message with a traceback. Running your code with the `tiles` provided in the question, returns the expected result (although the line with just `indexB` is clearly superfluous), so it's not possible to reproduce your problem unless you provide more information.

Comment: the only calls are the one above. Here is the tester code that I think is causing the issue. I'm not sure if there is a problem with my code or the tester code....https://github.com/ikokkari/PythonProblems/blob/main/tester109.py

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code, without `[![` in the beginning produces expected results.

Comment: i corrected it now. I used the test cases when calling the function and it worked correctly but I think there is something wrong with the tester code which I can't figure out

Comment: The question concerns *your* code. Problems with another ~3K lines of code should be addressed to the author.

Comment: The problem is with this code though - it's pretty convoluted...

Comment: is it my code or the tester code?

Comment: The tester code is fine, see below

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the expected results for the provided test cases. However, the code you linked generates far more test cases, so it's likely the problem only occurs when a test case is presented that's not covered by those.

Your algorithm seems very convoluted for what is asked. You loop `i` over the length of `tiles` - 1, and compute indices to compare in a way that's hard to track.

For any series of tiles, `indexA` and `indexB` will have these values in order:

```
i = 0: 0, 1 -> 0, 0 -> 1, 0 if tiles [0][1] == tiles [1][0], 0, 0 otherwise
i = 1: 1, 0 -> 2, 0 if tiles [1][1] == tiles[2][0], 1, 0 otherwise
       0, 0 -> 1, 0 if tiles [0][1] == tiles[1][0], 0, 0 otherwise
i = 2: 2, 0 -> 2, -1 -> 3, -1 if tiles [2][0] == tiles[3][-1], 2, -1 otherwise
       1, 0 -> 1, -1 -> 2, -1 if tiles [1][0] == tiles[2][-1], 1, -1 otherwise
       0, 0 -> 0, -1 -> 1, -1 if tiles [0][0] == tiles[1][-1], 0, -1 otherwise
...
i = 6: here indexB can become -2
```

I could write out the whole sequence, but clearly it's possible for `indexB` to become negative below -2, which would cause the error. Every iteration where `i` is odd, depending on the tiles, `indexB` may get lowered, and it is never raised.

For example:

```
domino_cycle([(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1)])
```

Should return `True` but tries to access `[-3]` of a tile, which it obviously doesn't have.

A simpler implementation like this won't have that problem:

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    return (
        # you check this as well and it helps to avoid errors with the rest
        tiles == [] or
        # the only check that won't be performed by the logic that follows
        (tiles[-1][1] == tiles[0][0] and
        # every 2nd pip value must match the 1st pip value of every paired tile
         all(a[1] == b[0] for a, b in zip(tiles, tiles[1:])))
    )
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do exactly, as an algorithm, so I can't really provide guidance on how to fix it. You should provide an explanation of your desired logic if you need help fixing your own solution.

If you're not allowed to use `zip()`, this is more or less the same:

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    return (
        tiles == [] or
        (tiles[-1][1] == tiles[0][0] and
         all(tiles[i][1] == tiles[i+1][0] for i in range(len(tiles) - 1)))
    )
```

If you're also not allowed to use `all()` (at this point, you're apparently not learning Python, but basic algorithms), this is the whole thing without:

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    if tiles == []:
        return True
    if tiles[-1][1] != tiles[0][0]:
        return False
    for i in range(len(tiles) - 1):
        if tiles[i][1] != tiles[i+1][0]:
            return False
    return True
```

You can keep going, without `range()`:

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    if tiles == []:
        return True
    if tiles[-1][1] != tiles[0][0]:
        return False
    i = 0
    while i < len(tiles) - 1:
        if tiles[i][1] != tiles[i+1][0]:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

That's just a longer way to write the same thing again. But it doesn't answer what was wrong with your algorithm, other than it simply cannot work. It's unclear what you were trying to achieve with the two indices.

Regarding finding the problem, here's your code with a simple debugging `print` statement, in case your misguided teacher is thinking learning to code with a plain text editor is the best idea:

```
def domino_cycle(tiles):
    indexA = 0
    indexB = 1
    if tiles == []:
        return True
    if tiles[0][0] != tiles[-1][1]:
        return False
    for i in range(len(tiles)-1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            indexB -= 1
        print(f'iteration i=={i}: tiles[{indexA}][{indexB + 1}] == tiles[{indexA + 1}][{indexB}]')
        if tiles[indexA][indexB + 1] == tiles[indexA + 1][indexB]:
            indexA += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Output on a that failing test case:

```
iteration i==0: tiles[0][1] == tiles[1][0]
iteration i==1: tiles[1][1] == tiles[2][0]
iteration i==2: tiles[2][0] == tiles[3][-1]
iteration i==3: tiles[3][0] == tiles[4][-1]
iteration i==4: tiles[4][-1] == tiles[5][-2]
iteration i==5: tiles[5][-1] == tiles[6][-2]
iteration i==6: tiles[6][-2] == tiles[7][-3]
```

That's your problem right there.

Comment: how did you find that problem?

Comment: By simply stepping through the code and looking at the values of `indexA`, `indexB` and how the logic works. I wrote down what I saw in the text above to explain what was going on. You could also add some `print` statement to get output similar to that automatically, which is what I would have done if I hadn't spotted the issue after the first 2 iterations. Using an IDE that allows interactive debugging is highly recommended (many do, like PyCharm or VSCode)

Comment: Another more brute force approach to finding a problem like this (though not as thorough) would have been to generate a massive test set and see what example breaks it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a brute force approach as I can only use loops, arithmetic operators, and conditionals to solve the problem

Comment: your code is clean but I can't use it

Comment: The point of a course in coding is not to find the right code, it's to understand the problem and find a way to code that solves it efficiently, in a readable fashion and of course correctly. You don't want to be that guy in the office that just faffs about with Excel for 2 weeks to almost get it right while a colleague would have written a script that solves the whole problem in an hour. Trust me, there's plenty of those around already.

Comment: hey Grismar, the code still crashes and doesn't work with the tester code

Comment: Then the remaining issue is likely in the setup your teacher has created - you probably need to submit your code in some specific format, perhaps that's failing. I can't tell what your teacher is doing with the submitted results - you'll have to take that up with them. I'm confident the presented solution is valid, for the problem as presented. Perhaps there are further constraints you're not sharing - but I think I've told you more than  enough to be able to resolve that.